# get attribute value from multiple elements with same name and attribute value of one other element in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have got a xml file which looks like this:

```
<events>
    <event id="12345">
        <option href="1"></option>
        <option href="2"></option>
        <option href="3"></option>
        <option href="4"></option>
    </event>
</events>
```

I am trying to select a pair of information from these nodes: the event id (12345) and the attribute of the elements option

```
var nodeWithOptions = from n in xml.Descendants("event")
                      select new
                      {
                           id = n.Attribute("id").Value,
                           options = n.Elements("option").Attributes("href").ToString(),
                      };
```

unfortunately this produces the following for options inside my foreach-loop: item.options = "System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+d__8"

What I want is: 12345, 1234 (yes I do not mind if the attribute value of the 4 option elements are in one string. And I also cannot change the xml file and I would prefer to use only linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nodeWithOptions = from n in xml.Descendants("event")
                      select new
                      {
                           id = (string)n.Attribute("id"),
                           options = n.Elements("option")
                                      .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("href"))
                                      .ToList(),
                      };
```

This will you `List<string>` with values of `href` attribute on `option` elements under given `event` element.